# Vector Equation

Tags: vector-spaces

Find a vector equation for the line passing through the point $(5,-1)$ and perpendicular to the vector $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

How do I do this?

My attempt has got me $$\begin{bmatrix}5\\-1\end{bmatrix} + r\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ but the answer states
$$\begin{bmatrix}5\\-1\end{bmatrix} + r \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer and the other answer you were given are both correct.  Any answer of the form 
$[5\ -1]^T + r\mathbf{v}$, with $\mathbf{v}$ a nonzero vector normal to $[ 1\ 1]^T$, is correct. You used $[-1\ 1]^T$ and someone else used $[1 -1]^T$, which are both normal to $[1\ 1]^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Using the vector $\vec{u}(1,1)$, the leading vector of the line could be $\vec{v}(\color{blue}{-1},\color{red}{+1})$ since $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v}=0$. Now we can have $$\frac{x-5}{\color{blue}{-1}}=\frac{y-(-1)}{\color{red}{+1}}=t$$

Answer (score 0):

The angular coefficient of the line is $m=-1$. thus the parametric equation is
$$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
x= & 5 + \lambda \\ 
y= & -1 -\lambda
\end{matrix}\right.$$
which lead to the cartesian equation $y=-x+4$